# Creating a triangle shape at the bottom of layout

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, material-components-android, material-components

I'm working on an android application that contains a shape at the top of the activity and I'm trying to implement it but struggling to do it.
[image: the shape in the green color]

I have tried to create a drawable file that create a triangle shape and sets up the bottom corner radius to match the shape above but not working. anyone can help me, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [**`EdgeTreatment`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/EdgeTreatment) included in the official [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

Just extend the `EdgeTreatment` with something like:

```
public class MyTriangleEdge extends EdgeTreatment {

  private final float size;
  private final boolean inside;

  public MyTriangleEdge(float size, boolean inside) {
    this.size = size;
    this.inside = inside;
  }

  @Override
  public void getEdgePath(
      float length, float center, float interpolation, @NonNull ShapePath shapePath) {
    shapePath.lineTo(0, 0);
    shapePath.lineTo(center, inside ? size  : -size );
    shapePath.lineTo(length, 0);
  }
```

and then apply it:

```
MyTriangleEdge edgeTreatment = new MyTriangleEdge(height,false);

LinearLayout linearLayout= findViewById(R.id.xxxx);
ShapeAppearanceModel shapeAppearanceModel = new ShapeAppearanceModel()
    .toBuilder()
    .setBottomEdge(edgeTreatment)
    .build();

MaterialShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new MaterialShapeDrawable(shapeAppearanceModel);

ViewCompat.setBackground(linearLayout,shapeDrawable);
```

[image]

Also for edge treatments, the parent view must disable clipping of children by setting `android:clipChildren="false"` in xml.

Comment: thank you so much for the reply, but the toBuilder() method cannot be resolved.

Comment: @user8545027 You have to use at least the version 1.1.0 (currently 1.1.0-rc02)